# How to get access token instead of pointing to redirect URL in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, react-native, azure-ad-b2c

I've created a custom policy in my Azure AD B2C tenant from which I'm getting my user flow endpoint. At this point I am able to log my registered user in and after a successful login attempt it redirects me to my redirect URL (which in my case is https://jwt.ms) where my access token is decoded.

What I'm doing right now is opening the same user flow endpoint in a react native app using `WebView`. It works perfectly but it then redirect to my redirect URL (https://jwt.ms) which I dont want. What I want is to return me the access token which I can get after a successful login so I can use the token to get the user information by decoding it.

How can I get access token instead of my app pointing to redirect URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was digging for a solution and found [this](https://sonyarouje.com/2019/02/07/react-native-library-for-azure-ad-b2c/) library. This library takes your existing AADB2C tenant and returns you the access token.

Note you might want to edit `onNavigationStateChange` function in `LoginView.js` to close the webview and redirect your app to a specific screen after login.

Comment: Is silent authentication possible with this library?